# What is refs/for/master when not using Gerrit?

Tags: git, github, gerrit

If I understand correctly, `refs/for/` is a special namespace that's [used in Gerrit for uploading changes](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/Documentation/intro-user.html#upload-change).

However, out of habit, instead of `git push origin master`, I've just done `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master` on **a non-Gerrit repo**, which apparently worked:

```
$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
Enumerating objects: [...]
[...]
To github.com:fstanis/myrepo.git
 * [new branch]      HEAD -> refs/for/master
```

This apparently created a new branch on origin, but this branch isn't listed when I try `git branch -r` and isn't shown in GitHub's UI. What exactly happened here? Where do commits pushed to `refs/for/master` "go" when not using Gerrit?

Comment: _where do commits ... go_ - they go to `origin/refs/for/master`, where you put them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pushed `refs/for/master` reference to remote you have created new [namespace](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitnamespaces) for references,  ang gave it name `for`.

Long story short, it allows to create default subset of references for each user to operate on and avoid name conflicts for refs used by different groups of repository users.

Users can set their own configuration in [`remote.remote_name.fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remoteltnamegtfetch) and [`remote.remote_name.push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remoteltnamegtpush) configuration values so that most common operations with branches and tags (`pull`, `push`, `fetch` etc.) would use their preferred namespace instead of default one defined by repository owner.

Maybe it is easier to understand if you think that **git** creates its own hardcoded namespaces when you create repository with all default configuration, one for branches (`heads`) and one for tags (`tags`) so that you do not need to prefix your branch and tag names in every operation with branches or tags

Comment: Thanks, while this was sort-of explained in the comments, your explanation makes a lot of sense so I'm making it accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You've just created a reference on `origin` called `refs/for/master`. You'll see it if you run `git ls-remote`. The reason you don't see it with `git branch -v` is that it's on the remote, not in your local repository. Normally branches go into `refs/heads`.

Example with your github repo from the comments:

```
$ git ls-remote
From https://github.com/fstanis/test.git
6f073e5b9326e5faae3c3a52db352acba5b1e1b9    HEAD
ca16131c993c8cbf7aeb6b045186af0072a27e9e    refs/for/master
6f073e5b9326e5faae3c3a52db352acba5b1e1b9    refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Hm, `git branch -r` doesn't show it either. It prints only `origin/HEAD -> origin/master` and `origin/master`. But the remote branch is definitely there, I just attempted to push to it and the remote rejected it.

Comment: Oh, maybe non `refs/heads` are hidden by default. If you go hunt in the `git remote` and `git branch` docs I'm sure you'll find the flag that shows you those.

Comment: I just tried it on a new repo and GitHub's UI doesn't show it either: https://github.com/fstanis/test

Comment: Found it. Editing answer.

Comment: Great, `git ls-remote` does see it! Interestingly, `git checkout -- refs/for/master` doesn't work, but `git reset -- refs/for/master` works and `git show-ref` also doesn't see it.

Comment: Yeah, the normal namespace is `refs/heads`. A lot of commands assume that.

Comment: The `--` syntax on checkout and reset means what follows is paths. On checkout, there was no such file to check out so it failed, on reset, well, it reset the path to what was in the commit, which was nothing. If you had staged a 'refs/for/master' file, it would have unstaged it.

Comment: @jthill you're right, I got it backwards - `git checkout refs/for/master --` is what I wanted (which also doesn't seem to work). Similarly, `git rebase refs/for/master` doesn't seem to work, but both work if I just use the hash I get from `git ls-remote`.

Comment: You can use `git fetch` to get refs from outside the normal namespace.

Comment: I did, but even after I fetch them, I can't checkout or rebase by name (but I can use `FETCH_HEAD`).